# With Flash, what are the different ways I can share library symbols across different FLA document classes?

Tags: flash, sharing, fla

For example, let's say I have two FLA document classes and each of them needs to use the banana MovieClip from the library. I don't want to have a copy of banana in each FLA. What options do I have for sharing the banana MovieClip among the two FLA document classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at creating [`SWC`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_SWC_file) files.

> An Adobe SWC file is a package of precompiled Flash symbols and ActionScript code that allows a Flash or Flex developer to distribute classes and assets, or to avoid recompiling symbols and code that will not change.

You can export SWC files by opting to create them whenever you publish your FLA, via <kbd>File > Publish Settings</kbd>:

[image]

Then in your other projects you can add the SWC to your library paths via <kbd>File > ActionScript Settings > Library path</kbd> and use the contents as expected:

[image]